# Unable to run the cronjob in ubuntu 10.10 server, EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a AWS EC2 instance with ubuntu 10.10 server.
I am trying to add a cron job to the list. But the cron job is not being executed.

I am actually uploading a particular file to aws s3 using s3cmd visit s3tools.org

What will be in the problem and also the solution.

Kindly help me out

Here is the bash script which has to be run

```
s3cmd put file-name s3://bucket_name/foder_name/file-name
```

Here is the job

```
* * * * * bash /path/to/file.sh
```

Comment: Any more information (command, logs, error messages)...

Comment: @Khaled hey I have added more info kindly have a look

Comment: Did you try to run the command manually under the same user? Also, it is better (in cron jobs) to refer the files using absolute path such as `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Does the cronjob run if you alter the command to something like this: * * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/cron-worked Have you tried altering your cron entry to: * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/file.sh

Comment: @Khaled I had a script which is running fine without the /bin/bash. yes I tried to run the script as user, its running fine I mean it will upload the file. But not cron

Comment: @Khaled okay thank you. I will follow your instructions..

Comment: Try to append `>> /tmp/mycron.log 2>&1` to the end of the cron job. Then, check the contents of the file `/tmp/mycron.log`.

Comment: I tried to append the log to mycron.log but I am not able to do it.Sometimes it executes and some times its not

Comment: @Khaled I just observed the logs its actually executing the script but I am not able to see the results. I mean the files are not being uploaded to the S3

Comment: Is this an interactive command/script? Did you get any error in the log file?

Comment: I did not get any error it showed that its actually being executed by ultimately the files are not being uploaded to s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution for this. The problem was I need to specify absolute path thats /usr/local/bin/s3cmd .